# on click image, expand div and play video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

What I want is to have a DIV divided in two, so that when clicking on the left DIV it expands to full height and starts playing the video, while closing it with a close button, the video pauses and the left DIV regains its normal height and width.
I found this code whitch is what im looking, but now I have to add the iframe and make it play and pause in while clicking the play and close button:

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CFNUJ/1/
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code that you already have?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the full YouTube player API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), you will want to create an empty div with an id of player for this script to hook into. Once the `onPlayerReady` event fires, you can hook into the javascript `player` object that the script creates and use it to manipulate the video player with calls like `player.playVideo()`. The iframe that replaces your empty div can then be modified like any other DOM element to change the size of the video player.

Note: The script I'm providing is cut down from the original API example so that it doesn't stop after 6 seconds

```
<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(){
    //Do Nothing for now
  }

</script>
```